# Are IPv6 addresses somehow customizable?

Tags: ipv6

I needed to look up the IP address of my university's homepage and was a bit surprised by the IPv6 address the lookup returned: `2001:7c0:7c0:0:0:0:babe:face`

Is the `babe:face` part random or algorithmically coupled to the usual IPv4 address or is it possible to customize an IPv6 address in this way?

Edit: To be precise, the address I mentioned belongs to one of the DNS servers and was provided as part of the WHOIS information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the absolutely huge address space provided by IPv6 what is usually allocated to users or companies are actually "address prefixes". This will be the address start, for example `2001:7c0:7c0:0`.

Your supplier will route all addresses that fall within that range to your router/firewall/network whereupon it is up to you which addresses are made public as in are not simply blocked by the firewall and have some kind of server running on them.

Chances are your network admin chose to statically allocate that machine address to their web server because it amused them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same as with IPv4 you could purchase a specific address. You can do the same with IPv6. If it is intranet you can force static IP and that can be whatever you want. In theory, you should respect public/private ranges but you don't really have to (on a private network/intranet) but this could lead to issues with some software that tries to connect to DNS on 1.1.1.1 and it ends up knocking on your laptop instead.